# Pulling p tags from multiple URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've struggled on this for days and not sure what the issue could be - basically, I'm trying to extract the profile box data (picture below) of each link -- going through inspector, I thought I could pull the p tags and do so.

[image]

I'm new to this and trying to understand, but here's what I have thus far:

-- a code that (somewhat) succesfully pulls the info for ONE link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# getting html

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Darius-Adams/Summary/28720'
req = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find('div', attrs={'class', 'main-container'})
playerinfo = container.find_all('p')


print(playerinfo)
```

I then also have a code that pulls all of the HREF tags from multiple links:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_links(url):

    links = []

    website = requests.get(url)
    website_text = website.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

        links.append(link.get('href'))

    for link in links:
        print(link)

        print(len(links))


get_links('https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022')
get_links('https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021')
get_links('https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020')
```

So basically, my goal is to combine these two, and get one code that will pull all of the P tags from multiple URLs. I've been trying to do it, and I'm really not sure at all why this isn't working here:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def get_profile(url):

    profiles = []

    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    container = soup.find('div', attrs={'class', 'main-container'})

    for profile in container.find_all('a'):

        profiles.append(profile.get('p'))

    for profile in profiles:
        print(profile)


get_profile('https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Darius-Adams/Summary/28720')
get_profile('https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Marial-Shayok/Summary/26697')
```

Again, I'm really new to web scraping with Python but any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Ultimately, my end goal is to have a tool that can scrape this data in a clean way all at once.

(Player name, Current Team, Born, Birthplace, etc).. maybe I'm doing it entirely wrong but any guidance is welcome!

Comment: What isn't working with the above?

Comment: @QHarr I'm getting a list of "NONE" when I run the p tag.. I thought that was how I'd be able to pull this profile box info based on the inspector? Maybe I'm just doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine your two scripts together and make requests for each player. Try the following approach. This searches for `<td>` tags that have the `data-td=Player` attribute:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th' : 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name" : name, "URL" : player_url}
        
        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data

urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2021',
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2020',
]


for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    
    for entry in data:
        print(entry)
```